# Finding roots of polynomials of arbitrary degree

Tags: analysis, polynomials

I asked this question on MO, but it has been tagged off-topic.

Is there any analogue of the method for expressing roots of polynomials of degree $5$ with elliptic and $\eta$-functions that generalizes to polynomials of degrees $n>5$?

More specifically: does there exist any ''reasonable'' sequence of ''reasonable'' finite sets of ''reasonable'' special functions such that for arbitrary polynomial of degree $d$ its roots are expressible by a unique term made out of coefficients of polynomial and functions from the $d$-th set?

By ''reasonable'' special functions I mean ones that has been investigated independently or have been already coined and are decently understood or are solutions to reasonable ODEs. By a reasonable sequence I mean basically something like a family of functions parametrized by $n \in \mathbb{N}.$

Comment: I present a bit of this material in a wider context in this [Computational Science answer](http://scicomp.stackexchange.com/a/1885/651), with some links for fuller exposition.